# Existence of a path or a cycle of length at least $\text{min}\lbrace 2\delta(G),|G|\rbrace$

Tags: graph-theory

This is a problem of Diestel's book of graph theory. It asks to show that every connected graph has a path or a cycle of lenght at least $\text{min}\lbrace 2\delta (G),|G|\rbrace$ which is curiously very similar to the exercise to show that every connected graph has a path of lenght at least $\text{min}\lbrace 2\delta (G),|G|-1\rbrace$ which I've already solved.
I don't know if I can conclude the first exercise from the second one... however, I was told to look at the sets $N(u)$ and $N^{+}(u)=\lbrace p_{i}\in P| p_{i+1}\in N(u)\rbrace$ where $u$ is the beggining vertex of P and $N(u)$ is its set of neighborhoods. It seems that $N^{+}(u)\cap N(u)\neq\emptyset$ concludes the proof but I really don't see why and the other case $N^{+}(u)\cap N(u)=\emptyset$ neither.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213357/connected-graph-with-minimum-degree