Proving lower bound for the length of a cycle in a 2-connected graph.
I'm trying to prove that every 2-connected graph $G$ has a cycle $C$ such that $\vert C\vert\ge\text{min}(\vert G\vert,2\kappa(G)$ where $\kappa(G)$ is the connectivity of the graph (may be larger than 2).
I'm having trouble getting started. I've tried to apply some recent theorems: The connectivity is at most the minimum degree of the graph, which I think lets me find a cycle of length $\kappa(G)$. The connectivity is equal to the maximum number of independent paths you can construct between any two vertices in the graph, which I'm not sure how to turn into a cycle.
Help getting started would be appreciated.

This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213357/connected-graph-with-minimum-degree

I figured it out!
The graph $G$ is guaranteed to have a cycle since it is 2-connected. Let $C$ be a maximum cycle in $G$.
If $\vert C\vert=\vert G\vert$ we are done. Otherwise there exists a vertex $x\in G\setminus C$.
By connectivity, there must be at least $\kappa(G)$ paths $P_1,\dots ,P_{\kappa(G)}$ from $x$ to $C$ whose pairwise intersection is $\{ x\}$. Let $c_1,\dots ,c_{\kappa(G)}$ be the ends of these paths in $C$.
If dist$(c_i,c_j)=1$ for some $i\ne j$, then $c_iP_ixP_jc_jC$ is a longer cycle. So dist$(c_i,c_j)\ge2$ for all $i\ne j$.
Then $\vert C\vert\ge2\kappa(G)$.
